# nginx: Is it possible to have an 'catch all' error_page?

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver

When looking at the documentation for nginx's [error_page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) directive, it seems that one has to manually list out every possible status code that nginx (or an upstream server) could return.

For example:

```
error_page   404          /404.html;
error_page   502 503 504  /50x.html;
error_page   403          http://example.com/forbidden.html;
error_page   404          = @fetch;
```

---

Is there anyway of producing a wildcard for ALL status codes that are not specified directly... For example:

```
error_page   404          /404.html;
error_page   5xx          /50x.html;
```

or

```
error_page   404          /404.html;
error_page   502 503 504  /50x.html;
error_page   @catchall    /5xx.html;
```

Comment: If you want to have one error page for all errors, you can do this via Server Side Includes. I wrote a blog post about that: https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html

Comment: @adriaan Does that work like only one page for all errors ? Also your blog says declare this in each (http, server )both directive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

Moreover, it is not recommended to blindly list all codes, as

- nginx allows to redefine all response codes, including ones you don't really want to redefine except in a few very specific situations (e.g. you don't normally want to redefine 304 (Not Modified), and probably not 302 (Found) unless there are very specific reasons);
- redefining some of the error codes might cause more harm than good (e.g. redefining 400 (Bad Request) is a bad idea).

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted to redefine any error codes, they just wanted a single template for the html. Also, 3xx response codes aren't error codes - I believe the question was only around 4xx and 5xx codes

Comment: @Bill, the OP was explicit enough and asked for "a wildcard for ALL status codes that are not specified directly". And even if the goal was to redefine only 4xx/5xx error codes rather than all status codes nginx allows one to redefine - this is still bad idea, as the answer explains.

Answer (score 1):

```
location {
  ...

  error_page
    301 302 303 304 307 308
    400 401 402 403 404 405 406 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 421 429
    500 501 502 503 504 505 507
    @errors;

  location @errors {
    internal;
    default_type "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    return 200 "$status\n";
  }
}
```

Responses can provide status messages like "404 Not Found" by defining a `map` for each HTTP code, as described in [One location block for all Nginx error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621915/one-location-block-for-all-nginx-error-codes/75514970#75514970)

Comment: I really want to +1 the effort that went into gathering all these codes, but overriding some of these codes (especially `301` and `302`) will ruin the site of anyone who doesn't understand that many of those aren't actually errors (such as `30{1,2}` being plain old redirects).