# How to deny with 404 on nginx

Tags: security, nginx, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I want to secure some locations in nginx by supplying deny/allow directives, but I do not want outsider to know that a location is denied. I want outsider to get 404, not 403 http code. My configuration snippet is

```
location /admin/ {
    uwsgi_pass myupstream1;
    include /path/to/uwsgi_params;

    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

When I try to visit /admin/ nginx responds with HTTP 403, but I want it respond with HTTP 404. Any recipe for this?

Answer (score 10):

```
error_page 403 404 /404.html;

location = /404.html {
    internal; #return 404
}

location /admin/ {
    uwsgi_pass myupstream1;
    include /path/to/uwsgi_params;

    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

[The 'internal' returns 404 by default.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal)

Adapted from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621915/nginx-error-pages-one-location-rule-to-fit-them-all)

Comment: Does this actually return the right error code, or just the right resource?

Comment: I haven't checked the response headers but I'd assume it's going to respond 403. I found another solution which might work a lot better.

Comment: But this will change all 403 to 404, or not? I like the other answer more where you add the `return 404;` line after deny.

Comment: This will indeed change all 403 responses to 404. If you wanted to make this behaviour specific to /admin/ you would move the 'error_page 403 404 /404.html;' into its location block

Comment: While this answer does work, the nginx docs suggest that the first line should have an assignment operator i.e. 'error_page 403 =404 /404.html;'

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way is to create a custom error page. In that page instead of showing http error code, you can specify a custom message.

Name an error page

> ```
> error_page 403 =404 /40X.html;
>
>     location /admin/ {
>         uwsgi_pass myupstream1;
>         include /path/to/uwsgi_params;
>         allow 127.0.0.1;
>         deny all;  
>     }
>
>     location /40X.html {
>     root path/to/public;
>     }
> ```

In your 40x.html you can write any message

> ```
> <html>
> <body> The requested resource is not available </body>
> </html>
> ```

place this 40x.html in your path/to/public directory

Comment: Thanks for this. Already had this in my config file for the 50x didn't know this was the way of doing things, really nice, know they don't know if a location actually exists or not :)

Comment: I verified the returned 404 headers with addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers - using `internal` in the `/40X.html` stanza (instead of `root path`) returns the default `404` page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "rewrite" instead of "deny all"

```
location /admin/ {
    uwsgi_pass myupstream1;
    include /path/to/uwsgi_params;

    #allow 127.0.0.1;
    #deny all;

    rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /404.php?id=$1;

}
```

Put 404.php into the root of your domain (eg _http://127.0.0.1/404.php) or change
"path/to/file/404.php?id=$1"

Answer (score -2):

**return 404;** will do what you want . Look bellow

```
    location /admin/ {
        uwsgi_pass myupstream1;
        include /path/to/uwsgi_params;

        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        #Following line returns 404
        return 404;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it is returning 404 on both allow and deny

Comment: It does not work. More over `deny` rule become non-working