# Nginx: setting the error page to a static file

Tags: nginx, configuration, system

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     default;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }

}
```

When the internal service at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` is not responding nginx return a *502 Bad Gatway error*.

**My question**: how can I configure nginx to returning a static html file, e.g. `/var/www/error.html`, when such error occurs?

---

**What I tried**

Taking a cue [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621915/nginx-error-pages-one-location-rule-to-fit-them-all/13624139#13624139) I tried this:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     default;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }

  error_page 404 502 /error.html;

  location = /error.html {
    internal;
    root /var/www;
  }

}
```

It's working fine if the service (on the port `8080`) is down, but when the service is up and I try to access the url `/error.html` nginx match the last location (returning me the static file) and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Why you want to access to `/error.html`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen On my server I have my error page on `/var/www/error.html` and I want to serve it in case of the 502 error. I don't want to access `/error.html`, it was only a try. What alternatives can I use?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I don't want to expose the error page when my service is up.

Comment: Noone will go to your `host/error.html` unless you put this link somewhere. Just don't do it and everything will be fine

Comment: @AlexeyTen :D yes, this is a good workaround, but it is not the best solution. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you really don't want to expose error page, you could use named location.

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     default;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    # probably you also need this
    # proxy_intercept_errors on;
  }

  error_page 404 502 @error;

  location @error {
    root /var/www;
    try_files /error.html /error.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing is that I don't need the `proxy_intercept_errors`, because my service have it's internal error page, and I want that page if it is running.

Comment: Then you don't need `404` in `error_page` directive also.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added it for my various test but probably you are right, I don't need it.

Comment: I found also useful add `$uri` in `try_files`, i.e.: `try_files $uri /error.html /error.html;`. In this way I can link images (and other resources) in the error.html, for example I can use `<img src="/images/logo.png" />`.